# sed with two conditions

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file that contains a bunch of lines.
I would like to remove entries from file which starts with `nnn` 
and are longer than 25 characters.

For now I am able only to make two separates `sed`:

```
sed '/^nnn/d' input.txt > output.txt
sed '/^.\{25\}./d' input.txt > output.txt
```

but this is not my goal.

Example input:

```
nnnASDDGfdgdsfndsjfndsjfdfgGHGHGhfhfd
nnnASDDGfdgdsfn
sadbSADSDDFSDFrrrRRRRRRRttTGGGG
```

Desired output:

```
nnnASDDGfdgdsfn
sadbSADSDDFSDFrrrRRRRRRRttTGGGG
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E '/^nnn.{23}/d' file
```

- `/^nnn.{23,}/` - match only line that starts with `nnn` and has more than 25 characters (`.{23,}` - match character sequence of at least 23 characters long)
- `d` - delete the matched line

---

The output:

```
nnnASDDGfdgdsfn
sadbSADSDDFSDFrrrRRRRRRRttTGGGG
```

---

The same with **`awk`** command:

```
awk '!/^nnn.{23}/' file
```

Comment: Thanks it works but T had to sligtly change to:
/^.\{26,\}/d

Comment: You don't need two conditions: `sed -E '/^nnn.{23}/d' infile` will do.

Answer (score 8):

This is best done by `awk`:

```
awk '/^nnn/ && length >= 25 { next } { print }' file
```

The `/^nnn/` will match the given regular expression ("line starts with `nnn`").  `length` (or `length($0)`) will return the length of the input line.  If the expression matches and the length is 25 or longer, the line is ignored, otherwise it's printed.  The `{ print }` may be replaced by just `1` if it feels too long to type.

Or,

```
awk '!/^nnn/ || length < 25' file
```

This does the same thing but with the inverse condition.  If the line does not match the expression, or if it's less than 25 characters, then it's printed. Other lines are ignored.

Both of these produce

```
nnnASDDGfdgdsfn
sadbSADSDDFSDFrrrRRRRRRRttTGGGG
```

for the given input data.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like:

```
sed -e '/^nnn/!b' -e '/.\{26\}/d'
```

Or:

```
sed '/^nnn/{/.\{26\}/d;}'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about humble `grep`

```bsh
$ grep -v '^nnn.\{23\}' ip.txt
nnnASDDGfdgdsfn
sadbSADSDDFSDFrrrRRRRRRRttTGGGG

$ # if ERE is available
$ grep -vE '^nnn.{23}' ip.txt
nnnASDDGfdgdsfn
sadbSADSDDFSDFrrrRRRRRRRttTGGGG
```

> **-v, --invert-match**    Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

Answer (score 2):

With grep

```
grep -v '^nnn.\{23\}' infile
```