# Remove lines that contain two string matches

Tags: text-processing

How to delete all lines containing `def` AND `jkl` from the following file (lines 2 and 4)? I want the match to apply to sub-string matches of the fields, too. The fields in the file are space-separated.

```
$ cat test2.txt 
1. abc def ghi
2. def ghi jkl
3. jkl mno pqr
4. jkl def stu
5. vwx yza bcd
```

I managed to do it using a boolean `OR` (`\|`):

```
$ sed '/def.*jkl\|jkl.*def/d' test2.txt 
1. abc def ghi
3. jkl mno pqr
5. vwx yza bcd
```

Isn't there a simpler syntax with a boolean `AND`, something like `$ sed '/defANDjkl/d'` ?

I tried `sed '/def&jkl/d'`, `sed '/def&&jkl/d'`, `sed '/def\&jkl/d'` and `sed '/def\&\&jkl/d'`, but nothing works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `sed` specifically, you could do:

```
sed -e '/def/!b' -e /jkl/d
```

Where the first `e`xpression `b`ranches out (which prints the line as we didn't pass the `-n` option) if `def` is not (`!`) found, and the second `d`eletes  if `jkl` is found. So in the end the line is deleted only  if both `def` and `jkl` are found.

To generalise to any number of regexps, you can do:

```
sed '
  /regexp1/!b
  /regexp2/!b
  /regexp3/!b
  d'
```

Note that `\|` is not a standard *basic regular expression* (BRE) operator. Few `sed` implementations support it. Standard BREs have neither OR nor AND operators. Standard EREs (*extended regular expressions*, as supported by `sed -E` with many `sed` implementations) do support OR (`|`) but not AND.

The [ast-open](https://github.com/att/ast) implementation of `sed` does have a AND operator (`&`) in its *augmented* regexps enabled with `-A` or `-X`, but you'd need:

```
sed -A '/.*def.*&.*jkl.*/d'
```

as `A&B` matches on strings that are matched by both `A` and `B`.

With `sed` implementations that support perl-like regexps (like `sed -P` with ast-open's or `sed -R` with `ssed`), you can use look ahead operators:

```
sed -P '/^(?=.*def)(?=.*jkl)/d'
```

Which matches on the start of the line provided it is followed (`(?=...)`) by any number of characters (`.*`) followed by `def` and that it is followed by any number of characters followed by `jkl`.

There are more implementations of `grep` that support `-P` than `sed` though, so:

```
grep -vP '^(?=.*def)(?=.*jkl)'
```

would be more portable.

Comment: Great and thorough answer ! Yes, `$ ssed -R '/^(?=.*def)(?=.*jkl)/d'` works indeed too. That being said, AdminBee's `awk` solution is shorter and simpler. But I'll mark this answer as accepted, since my question was about `sed`.

Comment: Your first suggestion could be condensed into one expression with `sed '/def/!b; /jkl/d'`

Comment: @DavidHusz, that would not be standard `sed` syntax. In several `sed`s including the original one, `b; /jkl/d` branches to the `"; /jkl/d"` label.

Answer (score 11):

Since you state that substring-match would also constitute a deletion criterion, the following `awk` program should work:

```
~$ awk '!(/def/ && /jkl/)' test.txt
1. abc def ghi
3. jkl mno pqr
5. vwx yza bcd
```

This will only print lines that do *not* fulfill the condition "line matches `def` and `jkl`".

If it has to be `sed`, you can adapt [this answer by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428520/377345):

```
~$ sed -e '/def/!b' -e '/jkl/d' test.txt 
1. abc def ghi
3. jkl mno pqr
5. vwx yza bcd
```

Answer (score 11):

You could also use perl instead. In this case, its syntax is far easier to understand than `sed`:

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless /def/ && /jkl/' test2.txt 
1. abc def ghi
3. jkl mno pqr
5. vwx yza bcd
```

Or

```
$ perl -ne '/def/ && /jkl/ || print' test2.txt 
1. abc def ghi
3. jkl mno pqr
5. vwx yza bcd
```

or even:

```
$ perl -ne '(/def/ && /jkl/) ? next : print' test2.txt 
1. abc def ghi
3. jkl mno pqr
5. vwx yza bcd
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -ne '
  /def/G;/jkl/G
  /\n\{2\}/!P
' file
1. abc def ghi
3. jkl mno pqr
5. vwx yza bcd
```

---

```
$ perl -MList::Util=all -lne 'my $l.= $_;
    print if ! all { $l =~ /\Q$_/ } qw/def jkl/;
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne '.put  unless .grep: all(/def/ , /jkl/);'
```

OR

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep: { !/def/ || !/jkl/ };'
```

---

OR (Raku equivalent of @terdon's Perl5 code):

```
raku -ne '.put unless /def/ && /jkl/;'
```

OR

```
raku -ne '/def/ && /jkl/ || .put;'
```

OR

```
raku -ne '(/def/ && /jkl/) ?? {next} !! .put'
```

Sample Input:

```
1. abc def ghi
2. def ghi jkl
3. jkl mno pqr
4. jkl def stu
5. vwx yza bcd
```

Sample Output:

```
1. abc def ghi
3. jkl mno pqr
5. vwx yza bcd
```

Briefly, the first two answers using the `-ne`(non-autoprinting) linewise flag along with Raku's `grep` routine. The next three answers are the Raku equivalent of @terdon's Perl(5) answers.

The first two (`grep`) lines of code are interesting in that they use two different mechanisms: the first uses an `all` junction (often called on Sets within Raku), while in the second example `grep` is run on a `{}`code block, which boolifies to a True/False.

A nice variation on the first two (`grep`) results is taking advantages of extra parameters (`:k`, `:v`, `:kv`, `:p`) available in the `grep` routine. For example, simply adding the `:p` pairs ('adverbial' parameter) instructs the code to output results as numbered pairs:

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep( { !/def/ || !/jkl/ }, :p );'
```

Sample Output (with index):

```
0 => 1. abc def ghi
2 => 3. jkl mno pqr
4 => 5. vwx yza bcd
```

https://raku.org